# remove matching images from two Arrays

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm making a snap game were I'm trying to remove two images from an array so they don't reappear again when first random card and second random card match. Is there any way I can do this? Thanks

```
var cardNamesArray: [String] = ["sad", "sleepy","angry"]

var cardNamesArray2: [String] = ["triste", "cansado","enfadado"]
```

Generates a random card for the first Array

```
   firstRandomNumber = Int (arc4random_uniform(3))
   let firstCardString:String = self.cardNamesArray[firstRandomNumber]
   self.FirstCardImageView.image = UIImage(named: firstCardString)
```

Generates a random card for the second Array

```
   SecondRandomNumber = Int (arc4random_uniform(3))
   let SecondCardString:String = self.cardNamesArray2[SecondRandomNumber]
   self.SecondCardImageView.image = UIImage(named: SecondCardString)
```

If they match player score 1 point

```
        @IBAction func SnapButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {

        if firstRandomNumber == SecondRandomNumber {

        print("index match")

        self.playerScore += 1
        self.playerScoreLabel.text = String(self.playerScore

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try to remove images from an Array itself. Once the random number matches, you can do that!

```
if firstRandomNumber == SecondRandomNumber {

    print("index match") 
    self.playerScore += 1
    self.playerScoreLabel.text = String(self.playerScore
    cardNamesArray.removeAtIndex(firstRandomNumber)
    cardNamesArray2.removeAtIndex(SecondRandomNumber)

    if cardNamesArray.count == 0 && cardNamesArray2.count == 0{
        print("User Won")
    }else{
        print("Continue Playing")
    }
}
```

> Crash Update:

Replace the below two lines in your code with mine

```
firstRandomNumber = Int (arc4random_uniform(UInt32(cardNamesArray.count)))

SecondRandomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(cardNamesArray2.count)))
```

Comment: the problem is that when they are matched the game crashes when the player generates a random card again.

Comment: "cannot convert value of type 'int' to expected argument type 'UInt32'

Comment: firstRandomNumber = Int (arc4random_uniform(UInt32(cardNamesArray.count)))

Comment: one more question, how can I end the array so it doesn't go out of range?

Comment: If you have replaced the above lines then there will no out of range. Once array count will be zero no random number will be generated!

Comment: would it work so that when the last index of the array is matched having like "you have won" instead of having the user pressing random button again and making the game crash.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a dictionary object in the Array.

Instead of

```
var cardNamesArray: [String] = ["sad", "sleepy","angry"]
```

You may use

```
Class CardItem{

   var name = ""
   var isDisplayed:Boolean?

}
```

And now

```
var cardNamesArray: [CardItem] = [CardItem(name:"sad",isDisplayed:false), CardItem(name:"sleepy",isDisplayed:false),CardItem(name:"angry",isDisplayed:false)]
```

Here is your random chunk:

```
SecondRandomNumber = Int (arc4random_uniform(3))

var uniqueItem = self.cardNamesArray2[SecondRandomNumber]

let SecondCardString:String = uniqueItem.name

self.SecondCardImageView.image = UIImage(named: SecondCardString)

uniqueItem.isDisplayed = true
```

So when you next time generate random number just check item's isDisplayed property.